# Asp Net MVC form causes source html to be displayed as output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

ASP NET 4.6.1 MVC5
steps to reproduce:

Razor View Create.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@model DumpZero.ViewModels.GiftViewModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_WizardBar.cshtml";
}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2 id="PageTitle"></h2>
        </div>
    <div id="editMsg" hidden="hidden" class="col-md-8">
        <h4>@Resources.create_editmsg1</h4>
        <p style="color:red;">@Resources.create_editmsg2</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Gifts", new { id = Model.Product.ID }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "contact-form", id = "contact-form", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Product.UserID, new { @Value = User.Identity.GetUserId() });
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Product.ID, new { @Value = Model.Product.ID });
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Resources.Title } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Name, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" id="SubmitID">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" id="nextBtn" value="@Resources.Create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedCategoryID, Model.CategoryList, Resources.Choose_Parent_Category, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "selectedCategoryID" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedCategoryID, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6" id="ChildrenDivID">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.selectedChildCategoryID, Model.ChildCategoryList, Resources.Choose_Child_Category_optional, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "selectedChildCategoryID" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control textarea", rows = "15", placeholder = Resources.Description } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Description, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
```

GiftViewModelMetaData:

```
using CultureResources;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace DumpZero.ViewModels
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(GiftViewModelMetaData))]
    public partial class GiftViewModel { }
    public class GiftViewModelMetaData
    {
        //[Display(Name = "Category", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "field_required")]
    public int selectedCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Location", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    public string GeoLocation { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "field_required")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_10_50")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\p{L}\p{Nd}\s]+$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CharsValidation")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "field_required")]
    [StringLength(500, MinimumLength = 100, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "Validation_100_500")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[/«»“”?.,:：;!¡¿。、·'-'\""\p{L}\p{Nd}\s]+$", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), ErrorMessageResourceName = "CharsValidation_extended")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And relevant controller httppost method:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Users")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Product product, int selectedCategoryID, int? selectedChildCategoryID)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                string productName = product.Name;
                string productDescription = product.Description;
                string message = "";
                string subject = "";

                if (product.ID.HasValue)  //existing product: only user 'owner' is granted editing / TODO: REMOVE ADMIN WHEN TESTING IS OVER
                {
                    int productID = product.ID.Value;
                    if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.Identity.GetUserId() == product.UserID) // check admin or product owner
                    {
                        product = db.Products.Find(productID);
                        ProductModified(product);
                        product.Name = productName;
                        product.Description = productDescription;

                        if (selectedChildCategoryID > 0) //subcategory selected
                        {
                            product.CategoryID = selectedChildCategoryID.Value;
                        }
                        else // no subcategory selected
                        {
                            product.CategoryID = selectedCategoryID;
                        }
                        subject = Resources.email_updatedgift_subject;
                        message = Resources.email_updatedgift_content;
                    }
                }
                else  //new product
                {
                    if (selectedChildCategoryID > 0) //subcategory selected
                    {
                        product.CategoryID = selectedChildCategoryID.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        product.CategoryID = selectedCategoryID;
                    }
                    product.Name = productName;
                    product.Description = productDescription;
                    product.IsDeleted = false;
                    product.IsApproved = false;
                    product.UserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                    db.Products.Add(product);
                    subject = Resources.email_newgift_subject;
                    message = Resources.email_newgift_content;
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
                loadViewModelSelectedCategory(fillViewModel(product.ID.Value));
                await sendNewGiftMail(product, message, subject);
                return RedirectToAction("Create", new { id = product.ID });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
            }
        }

        return RedirectToAction("InternalServerError", "Error", viewModel);
    }
```

IMPORTANT: Please note client validation is disabled (jquery validate and validate.unobtrusive are not present) while server side validation is enabled in ViewModel

Here's the form:

[image]

As I click on "Create" form input button intentionally leaving fields empty I would expect server side validation to fail.
Now here is the response:

[image]

That is, in reply to my input form, nothing but full html source page is printed out.
Confused...

Here's error as registered by Elmah:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'selectedCategoryID' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult] Create(DumpZero.Models.Product, Int32, System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' in 'DumpZero.Controllers.GiftsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Again: I would expect server validation OR an error to pop up, not to have html source of razor view displayed as output.

Comment: This is strange. Anyway, I think you want to use `return View(product)` instead of `return RedirectToAction("InternalServerError", "Error", viewModel);` when the model is not valid (e.g blank fields).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using an async action method instead of ajax?

Comment: @ alisson: when modelstate is invalid product is empty and loading view would fail. In any case the problem is: 1. modelstate is not valid as required fields are missing, so redirect should load errorpage BUT 2. server side validation in viewmodel(metadata) should intercept it and just show "this field is required" under offending fields. 3. In any case that does not explain why a full "https://localhost:44324/Gifts/Create"  html source page is being displayed instead of 2. or 1.